# How to switch focus among 50 text fields in QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I want to switch focus from one field to the next when the user presses Enter: how would I go about it?

The items are arranged in a grid, as follows:

```js
Grid {
  x: 5
  y: 3
  rows: 5
  columns: 20
  spacing: 10

  Repeater { 
    model: 50

    TextField { 
      width: 28
      height: 50
      color: "green"
      text: "0000"
      font.pixelSize: 12

      validator: IntValidator {
        bottom: -256
        top: 256
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `TextField` inherits from `Item` you can use the existing focus chain using [`nextItemInFocusChain()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#nextItemInFocusChain-method).
Just add the following line to the `TextField`:

```
Keys.onEnterPressed: nextItemInFocusChain().forceActiveFocus()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using the `Key` attached property:

```
Grid {
    x: 5
    y: 3
    rows: 5
    columns: 20
    spacing: 10

    Repeater {
        id: rpt
        model: 50

        TextField {
            width: 28
            height: 50
            color: "green"
            text: "0000"
            font.pixelSize: 12

            Keys.onEnterPressed: rpt.itemAt(index + 1).focus = true

            validator: IntValidator {
                bottom: -256
                top: 256
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, it was not that hard, especially with the repeater ;-)